# How to create ORC or Parquet files from PHP code?

Tags: php, hive, parquet, orc, presto

Is there any library that can be used to write custom data files from a PHP app in ORC or Parquet format for Presto queries ?

If not what is the best practice in this case? Hopefully one that doesn't involve setting up Map Reduce cluster.

10X
- Nir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp project that provides a C++ implementation to write Parquet files without any use of MapReduce or the JVM. While there are already Python (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html), Ruby / GLib (https://github.com/red-data-tools/parquet-glib) and NodeJS (https://github.com/skale-me/node-parquet) bindings, there are none yet for PHP. But given those mentioned bindings, you should be able to write ones for PHP quite easily.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for bumping, but I felt this question should be updated.

Last year, I released the first publicly available PHP library for reading/writing Parquet files, `php-parquet`.
See https://github.com/jocoon/php-parquet and/or the published composer package https://packagist.org/packages/jocoon/parquet (`composer require jocoon/parquet`). It is a partial port of and inspired by *parquet-dotnet*, based on the Apache Thrift specifications.

As far as you don't have special compression needs (e.g. `snappy`), you won't need exotic PHP extensions. `BCMath` and `GMP` are required, due to the possibility of arbitrary-precision numbers and you'll need to have `zlib` available (AFAIK the most-used/typical compression method for Parquet files, to be more precise: *gzip*).

Basic usage instructions are provided on the respective github page.

DISCLAIMER: I'm the developer of this package. This is not meant as advertising. The library is published under the MIT license. Feel free to submit issues or contribute.

Comment: Jocoon/php-parquet repository has been archived by the owner on Dec 10, 2022. It is now read-only. The author suggests using the codename/parquet package instead.

Answer (score 1):

We’ve Apache licensed https://github.com/skipprd/php-parquet, a PHP binding for the C++ https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp implementation that’s been battle tested by skippr.io.

Pleased to see another effort on jocoon/php-parquet too. So now there’s a C binding and a PHP implementation to choose from! :)

DISCLAIMER: I'm the developer of this package. This is not meant as advertising. The library is published under the Apache license. Feel free to submit issues or contribute.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28687149)

Comment: This answer is exactly the same in nature as the answers above. It links to a new Apache licensed project and details the parent project it implements. I believe the answer and open source project it introduces provides real community value and deserves to remain published as we’re the answers above it.